# PHP header, Content type: image not allowing text

Tags: php, image, header, gd, content-type

I have a variable (`$output`) that is set to a string.

To mekt this string an image I'm using the [PHP: GD Library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php).

In particular the [imagestring()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php) function, which I'm using with a very slight modification:

```
<?php
// Create a 100*30 image
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $output, $textcolor); #here is my string $output

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

This is working as expected: It turns `$output` into an image.

So, my problem is (or my best guess at least):

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

Which, doesn't allow me to output any html after that.

So I read this question, which [asks if you can use two headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428004/how-can-i-use-multiple-php-header-content-types-on-the-same-page-is-this-possibl), which you can't, but [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428004/how-can-i-use-multiple-php-header-content-types-on-the-same-page-is-this-possibl/2428022#2428022) recommends, something like this: `<img src="my_img.php" />`

This of course would be fine, except I don't know how would this solve my issues since, since even if I knew the source to this image (**which I don't - so, that would be my first question, what's the path to the generated image***) I't would change the fact that the header is there and is not letting me output text.

So, I how would you approach this issue?

Thanks in advance!!

---

*I guess that would solve my issues since I could do this on an external file, and the just call the image (but maybe not since I would have to do an include and this would include the header too) as you see I'm a bit confused. Sorry :)

---

**UPDATE:**

So I'm seeing my question was confusing so I will add some more code to see if this clarifies my problem a little bit more:

```
<?php

$x = mt_rand(1,5);
$y = mt_rand(1,5);

function add($x, $y) { return $x + $y; }
function subtract($x, $y) { return $x - $y; }
function multiply($x, $y) { return $x * $y; }

$operators = array(
    'add',
    'subtract', 
    'multiply'
    );

$rdno = $operators[array_rand($operators)];

$result = call_user_func_array($rdno, array($x, $y));
session_start();
$_SESSION['res'] = $result;

if ($rdno == "add") {
    $whato = "+";
}elseif ($rdno == "subtract") {
    $whato = "-";
} else {
    $whato = "*";
}
$output = $x . $whato . $y . " = ";
?>
<form name="input" action="check.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="result" />
<input type="submit" value="Check" />
</form>
```

**I want `$output` to be a image** so this got me trying to use the PHP:GD script above, but I can't make put in the same file because of the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a separate PHP script which serves the image, then make an `<img>` tag that points to this script.

You can send information to the script using the querystring in the image URL.

Comment: Ok I think I see where you are going.

Comment: +1 - Where you want to place the image would need `<img src="yourcurrentscript.php" alt="Some alt text" />`. Because you're serving the `image/png` content type, it will treat whatever is returned from your script as an image.

Comment: @SLaks The problem is that I am dynamically generating this `$output` so I don't see how I could put it on another filem since the process would be generate the variable, I guess with a session send it to the file where the PHP:GD is executed, and then the get the source. It's kind of confusing, am I explaining myself? Thanks!!

Comment: @Akinator: You need to move that code to a separate file.  You can pass any information it needs in the querystring.

Answer (score 3):

Morbo says: "Windmills do not work that way! Goodnight!"

Which means that you need to bone up on how this all works. This issue points to you having a basic misunderstanding of your tools. HTML can't contain images, it contains links to images. So your script needs to be included from another page via an image tag. (or CSS)

However, all this is a good thing. It means that this script can have dynamic elements that produce a new image each time it is called. Or that it could password-protect your images so only logged-in users can see it.

There are a host of ways to use this. And once you realize the image is like a page to php, this opens new routes. Php can output anything. Word docs, excel, pdf, css, even JS. all of which can be used to do cool things.

Just think of the image as a separate page. You'll get it. It'll just click into place in your mind. One of those big 'aha' moments.

Comment: I'm not saying I may not be confused with some basic concepts, but in this case, I think is more a problem of expressing myself than this. I know html can't contain images :)

Comment: So in your question, the a tag with my_img.php in it. That file contains your image script. The file that the a tag is in is the page proper.

Comment: agreed but I'm not understanding how to link to it since when I have to call to it, I would "not yet be created" or so O think plase look at my update.

Comment: the PHP script you are calling will create the image on the fly. And not save it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

First, the path.

[From the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) :

> imagepng ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality [, int $filters ]]] )

It means that if you don't give a second argument (it is the case here), you don't have the path to a file but the data of the file / image ressource. The php file will be *understand* as a png file by the browser thanks to the header you give.

Second :

In your page (ie *index.php*), you could add this like that

```
<img src="myimg.php?output=[...]" />
```

and in your php script *myimg.php* you have it like this :

```
<?php
$output = $_GET['output'] // getting your text

// Create a 100*30 image
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, $output, $textcolor); #here is my string $output

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

2 separates files.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the image inline with `echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'. base64_encode(imagepng($im)) .'" />` instead of `<img src="my_img.php">`.
Do not set a content-type header! Your output is text/html what you don't have to announce as it's the default in most server setups.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP doesn't work that way. When your are serving image/png data, it as if you are serving a png file from the site, not an html file with an image in it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

my_img.php is not source to your image. It is a source to the script generating that image, or reading it from file and outputting directly into browser. Obviously the approach with img src would be the best, because you'll hide all "boring" implementation of displaying image string behind browser's mechanisms.