# how to use the content-type:image/jpeg properly?

Tags: php, sql-server, mime-types, content-type

I've created a page "student_picture.php" using the content-type:image/jpeg. im having problem when I want to add other text in that same page..

here is the sample of my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["StudentNo"])){
    header("location:login.php");
}

$StudentNo = $_SESSION['StudentNo'];

require("includes/connection.php");

$sql = "SELECT StudentPicture from dbo.Students where StudentNo = '$StudentNo'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $img = $row['StudentPicture'];

    if ($img == null ) {
        echo "<img src='img/default_pic.gif'>";
    } else {
        $img =  trim($img);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        echo $img;
    }

    echo $StudentNo;
}
?>
```

The image is successfully displaying but the echo $StudentNo is not displaying.. can anyone help me with my prob? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428004/how-can-i-use-multiple-php-header-content-types-on-the-same-page-is-this-possib

Answer (score 3):

You might need to use following code :

```
<?php 

$image = 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg';

$info = getimagesize($image);

header('Content-Type: '.$info['mime']);

echo file_get_contents($image);

exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you cannot display text while using the `Content-Type` of `image/jpeg`, or any other kind of image format that I know of. Text can only be displayed with `text/?`, or other exceptions such as `application/pdf`.

If you don't know how to display the image on a separate page while using a php file, just use:

```
<img src="path/to/yourphpfile.php" />
```

Just like any other image.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Yes I think so. I cannot add text when I'm using content-type:image/jpeg. I think I need to call the page that displays the image from another page. The problem is I don't know how to do that :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to `exit` your script, because the `header` is sent to the client browser. If the `$_SESSION["StudentNo"]` is not present the script will process and will try to ouput your image.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["StudentNo"])){
        header("location:login.php");
        die();
    }
```

And that is not a proper way to output an image, `echo "<img src='img/default_pic.gif'>";` with `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` is not ok, either you return without that header or you read the image:

```
if ($img == null){
    $img = 'img/default_pic.gif';
} else {
    $img =  trim($img);
}

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($img);
```

or you lose the header tag

```
if ($img == null){
    $img = "<img src='img/default_pic.gif'>";
} else {
    $img = "<img src='".trim($img)."'>";
}
echo $img;
```

So your script could be:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["StudentNo"])){
        header("location:login.php");
        die();
    }
    $StudentNo = $_SESSION['StudentNo'];

    require("includes/connection.php");

    $sql = "SELECT StudentPicture from dbo.Students where StudentNo = '$StudentNo'";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
        $img = $row['StudentPicture'];
        if ($img == null){
            $img = "<img src='img/default_pic.gif'>";
        } else {
            $img = "<img src='".trim($img)."'>";
        }
        echo $img;
        echo $StudentNo;
    }
?>
```

I don't know the functions inside your DB connection, but I think you should use something like `$row = sqlsrv_fetch_row( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);` and make without that `while`

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I'm going to try what you said. thankd a lot

Comment: i cannot output the image without the content-type:image/jpeg.. i will only get raw data without it..
i also having error in your code with readfile($img);

Comment: I clearly explained how you should output the image, `readfile` must has a valid path to the image

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting an image when it is found in the database, you would either need to include a dynamic img via

```
<img src="anotherscript.php">
```

Or generate a jpg file using one of the built in image libraries and storing its file name in that database rather than storing the raw data