# Dev server downloads page to xls just fine but

Tags: php, download

I have this code, which works locally but not live -
This receives a result from query on the database
currently the output is only sent to the browser - and not offered a download, like it does locally:

```
if($_POST['xls'] == 'on'){
$file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
$file_ending = "xls";
$ttype = date('m-d-Y-H:i:s');
header("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
//header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
//header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
//header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$ttype.$file_ending");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
}
```

both servers are linux, the live server running cPanel with php 5.2.17
I do not administer the cpanel server and cannot upgrade php

Thanks

Comment: You need to add something to the affect of `readfile("file.xxx");` after `header("Expires: 0");`

Comment: why are you trying to assign multiple content-types? this is not possible as far as i know.

Comment: I had added the 3 after the first only to now realize that that broke the download - I have removed them - now works locally, not live still

Comment: @user1815352 Try `header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");` see if that will help.

Comment: @Fred - tried that to no avail

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your filename doesn't have an extension. In php, `.` is used to concatenate - so right now your filename is `09-18-2013-01:31:30xls`. It probably doesn't like the colons either. Try this:

```
$ttype = date('m-d-Y-His');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$ttype.".".$file_ending);
```

Comment: You have a point about the concatenate, however this `15:40:43.php` did work on my server. However, it won't be usable on a Windows platform. The OP should change the colons to something other than that, either hyphens or underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
```

This might make browser to stream it into document instead of asking to download.

Comment: he should remove all but one content-type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428004/how-can-i-use-multiple-php-header-content-types-on-the-same-page-is-this-possib

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<?php 
$date = date("d/m/Y");
if($_REQUEST['cetak'] == 3){
    $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
    //$file_name= "somename.xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/$file_type"); 
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("content-disposition: attachment; filename=Report".$date.".xls");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 

}
?>
```